# Reference for: Every element of a finite field is the sum of two squares.

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, finite-fields

*Note: This is a [reference-request](/questions/tagged/reference-request) question. It doesn't require the usual level of context. I am **not** asking for a proof.*

It is well known that

> **Theorem:** Let $x\in F$ for a finite field $F$. Then there exist $a,b\in F$ such that $x=a^2+b^2$.

I need the theorem for my dissertation. Therefore, I need a reference, please.

For context: I am writing up [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4864151/104041) (with a citation and the appropriate credit, of course), which a theorem of mine in a draft of my dissertation now relies upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition 1 in [Vitaly Bergelson, Andrew Best, and Alex Iosevich, *Sums of Powers in Large Finite Fields: A Mix of Methods*, The American Mathematical Monthly, 128:8, pp. 701-718](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2021.1943117). This has the advantage of being open access.

Answer (score 1):

**L'Arithmétique des corps**, by Paulo Ribenboim.

Page 182, chapitre X:"Sommes des carrés"

Hermann París. Collection Méthodes. 1972.

There is an English translation.

Comment: Please link to the English translation.

Comment: Ribenboim is a great mathematician who has written many papers and several seminal books, the most of them in English. The book is extraordinary and the chapter X is relevant.